# HTML Radio button inside ASP.NET repeater C#

Tags: html, button, radio-button, repeater

I am trying to simply bind a HTML Input radio button inside a repeater :

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Outlets" runat="server" >
 <ItemTemplate>
    <input type="radio" name="Proposal" value="Test1" id="Radio1" checked="
<%#`GetSelectedValue(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"IsDefaultSelection"))%>" />`

    <label for="Test1">
              <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Label")%>
    </label>

  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

The GetSelectedValue method simply returns a string "checked" for the radio button to be selected, lets say the repeater had 3 items to loop and when the markup renders and If I inspect the element I see the correct value for the first radio button i.e. checked="checked" but on the UI the 3rd radio button gets selected even though its checked value="false", can someone guide me as to what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give this a try

```
<%# (bool)Eval("IsDefaultSelection") ? " checked=\"checked\" " : string.Empty %>
```

Basically the inclusion on the `checked` attribute is causing the `RadioButton` to be checked. You want to pull it out so the entire thing is rendered or the entire thing is absent.

Also keep in mind all your `RadioButtons` are going to be named `Test1` It might be a good idea to use a server side `RadioButton`.

Comment: Awesome, I was worried I had a syntax error, coding without Intellisense is always more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

The CHECKED attribute in HTML has no value associated with it.  You should only use this attribute if you want to select it.

You want something like:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Outlets" runat="server" >
 <ItemTemplate>
    <input type="radio" name="Proposal" value="Test1" id="Radio1" <%
    if (GetSelectedValue(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"IsDefaultSelection"))
        response.write("CHECKED");
%> />
    <label for="Test1">
              <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Label")%>
    </label>

  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Otherwise you could simply use the ASP.NET INPUT controls.